# How to get Unicode characters U+2713 and U+2717 to display in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, unicode, input-encodings

My document has `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in its preamble. I am trying to use the characters U+2713 (check mark) and U+2717 (ballot X), but I get the error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:✓ not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I understand that I could fix this either by loading a font containing these characters, or by using `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. But how do I determine which font (if any) includes these two characters? (More generally, how does one determine for a given character whether any font includes it?)

I have also tried the `utf8x` package (even though some say that is not a good idea), and it also fails (albeit with a different error message). I am aware that switching to XeTeX or LuaTeX could be a solution, but I'd like to try to get this working with just pdfTeX if that is possible.

Comment: There are some [online source](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/fontsupport.htm). But they are probably only available through XeTeX/LuaTeX. On the other hand if there only two characters you can do ``\catcode`\✓=\active\def✓{\includegraphics{...}}``.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Package `pifont` contains the characters (`\ding{51}` and `\ding{55}`) and package `newunicodechar` helps in assigning them to the Unicode slots:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{✓}{\ding{51}}
\newunicodechar{✗}{\ding{55}}

\begin{document}
Check mark: ✓, ballot x: ✗
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Worked great. Only problem I had was `! Font U/pzd/m/n/10=pzdr at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found` but I solved that by installing `texlive-fonts-recommended` (I'm using MacPorts)